# How can I get all roots $\lambda$ of $\det\left( A - \lambda B\right) = 0$ when B is singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 4 polynomials of $x, y$.

$
\mathscr{R}_j \colon \ d_{j0}\left(x\right) y^3 + d_{j1}\left(x\right)y^2 + d_{j2}\left(x\right)y + d_{j3}\left(x\right) = 0, \ j = 1, 2, 3, 4,  
$
where $d_{jk}$ is polynomial of $x$ of $k^{th}$ degree.

I changed 4 polynomials to matrix. that matrix is below.

$
\bigl[ D\left(x\right)\bigr]\pmb{m} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1x +c_1 &d_1x^2+e_1x + f_1 & g_1x^3 + h_1x^2 + i_1 x + j_1 \\
a_2 & b_2x +c_2 &d_2x^2+e_2x + f_2 & g_2x^3 + h_2x^2 + i_2 x + j_2 \\
a_3 & b_3x +c_3 &d_3x^2+e_3x + f_3 & g_3x^3 + h_3x^2 + i_3 x + j_3 \\
a_4 & b_4x +c_4 &d_4x^2+e_4x + f_4 & g_4x^3 + h_4x^2 + i_4 x + j_4 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y^3 \\ y^2 \\ y \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$

$a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ are arbitrary constants.

I want to find non-trivial solutions. So $\det{\bigl[D \bigr]}$ must be zero. But $det{\bigl[D \bigr]}$ is 6th degree polynomial of x. After that I found a new way. It is change type of problem to generalized eigenvalues problem. The Problem changes as follows.

$
\bigl[ A \bigr] \pmb{x} = \lambda \bigl[ B \bigr] \pmb{x}\\
\bigl[A \bigr] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&I_4&0\\
0&0&I_4\\
-D_0&-D_1&-D_2\\
\end{bmatrix}, \
\bigl[B\bigr]=
\begin{bmatrix} 
I_4&0&0\\
0&I_4&0\\
0&0&-D_2\\
\end{bmatrix},\
\pmb{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \pmb{m}\\ \lambda\pmb{m} \\ \lambda^2 \pmb{m}\end{bmatrix}, \\ I_4 = 4 \times 4 \ \text{identity matrix}, 0 = 4\times 4 \ \text{zero matrix}
\\
\bigl[D_0\bigr] =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&c_1&f_1&j_1\\
a_2&c_2&f_2&j_2\\
a_3&c_3&f_3&j_3\\
a_4&c_4&f_4&j_4\\
\end{bmatrix}, \
\bigl[D_1\bigr] =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&b_1&e_1&i_1\\
0&b_2&e_2&i_2\\
0&b_3&e_3&i_3\\
0&b_4&e_4&i_4\\
\end{bmatrix}, \
\bigl[D_2\bigr] =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&d_1&h_1\\
0&0&d_2&h_2\\
0&0&d_3&h_3\\
0&0&d_4&h_4\\
\end{bmatrix}, \
\bigl[D_3\bigr] =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&g_1\\
0&0&0&g_2\\
0&0&0&g_3\\
0&0&0&g_4\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

as you see. matrix $B$ is singular matrix. How can I find the roots?
Any feedback you can give me on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

PS. Please understand that English is not my native language and it is awkward.

Comment: Problems of the type : Finding a pair $(\lambda, \mathbf{x})$ solving $A \mathbf{x} = \lambda B \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x} \neq 0$ is called "Generalized Eigenvalue Problem". For this problem, we solve $\mbox{det}(A - \lambda B) = 0$. This is a well-studied problem and I remember Wilkinson wrote many papers on it. I hope other friends here will help on your query.